# How to change the output with a dynamic T-SQL pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

This is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE tpivot
    ([col1] varchar(80), [col2] varchar(80), [col3] varchar(80), [col4] varchar(80), [col5] varchar(80))
;

INSERT INTO tpivot
    ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5])
VALUES
    ('Datum', 'EC', 'Mastercard', 'Postfinance', 'VISA'),
    ('01.12.2014', '-204.9', '-88', '0', '-19'),
    ('02.12.2014', '-352.9', '0', '79.9', '-20'),
    ('03.12.2014', '-105', '-182', '0', '-436'),
    ('04.12.2014', '-371', '-122,9', '-751', '-343')

;
```

My goal is to turn the table so that the output look like this.

```
col1         col2         col3        col4        col5
Datum        01.12.2014   02.12.2014  03.12.2014  04.12.2014
EC           -204.9       -352.9      -105        -371
Mastercard  -88           0           -182        -112.9
Postfinance  0            -79.9        0          -751
VISA         -19          -20         -436        -346
```

I need to have a dynamic pivot since i import the table from a csv that could have different amount of columns each time.

Can someone help me? I can't even get a static pivot to work :(

Thanks

Comment: Pls help me with this one :(

Comment: why not to transform existing csv before importing? for example in Excel, you can open csv, transpose the whole data matrix and save back. Sometimes it is much easier to change input format than process data using wrong tools. mixing different data types using varchars and output them in the same dataset is not a good practice. 
try to change the way you solving this task

Comment: This is not really what pivoting is. You start out with columns `col1` - `col5` and your desired output has the same columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution with dynamic SQL.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tPivot') IS NOT NULl
    DROP TABLE tpivot;

CREATE TABLE tpivot
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), [col1] varchar(100), [col2] varchar(100), [col3] varchar(100), [col4] varchar(100), [col5] varchar(100));
INSERT INTO tpivot
    ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5])
VALUES
    ('Datum', 'EC', 'Mastercard', 'Postfinance', 'VISA'),
    ('01.12.2014', '-204.9', '-88', '0', '-19'),
    ('02.12.2014', '-352.9', '0', '79.9', '-20'),
    ('03.12.2014', '-105', '-182', '0', '-436'),
    ('04.12.2014', '-371', '-122,9', '-751', '-343');

DECLARE @ColList VARCHAR(MAX),
        @IdList VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @ColList = COALESCE(@ColList + ',','') + QUOTENAME(A.COLUMN_NAME),
        @IdList = COALESCE(@IdList + ',','') + QUOTENAME(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'tPivot'
        AND COLUMN_NAME ! ='ID'

--SELECT @ColList
--SELECT @IdList


EXEC (
'WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID,
                Column_Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY col) row_num,
                val
        FROM tPivot A
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Column_Name AS COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''tPivot'' ) B
        ON A.ID = B.ORDINAL_POSITION - 1
        UNPIVOT
        (
            val for col in (' + @colList + ')
        ) unpvt
    ) A
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(val) FOR column_name IN (' + @colList + ')
    ) pvt
)

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
            row_num,
            coalesce(' + @colList + ') val
    FROM cte
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(val) FOR ID IN (' + @IdList + ')
) pvt'
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much. Hehe it's not easy for me to make this dynamic so if you would like to help me with that to i would be really grateful.

Comment: I understand. I used to be TERRIBLE at writing dynamic SQL. It's all about taking it one step at a time and practice! So what I do is write my script out, then I look for what parts need to be "dynamic" like your changing number of column names. I put those in variables. Then add single quotes around my script and start putting in my dynamic variables. Then I SELECT 'my code' and run the returned code in a new query window. Debug it and try again until it works. Once I get it to work, I change SELECT to EXEC('my code') and voila! Dynamic SQL is born! :)